# Needing help with vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

The positive numbers with **x** + **y** and e**x** redefined to equal the usual **xy** and
**x**
c do satisfy the eight rules. Test rule 7(e( **x** + **y**) = e**x** + e**y**) when e = 3, **x** = 2, **y** = 1. (Then
**x** + **y** = 2 and e**x**= 8.) Which number acts as the "zero vector"? The answer is the number one, but why? What's going on?

This is a practice problem from Gilbert Strang's linear algebra. Is this question referring to a vector space of 1, where x and y are vectors in a single 1d direction? I'm just very lost with this question(and vector spaces in general) as I'm not used to the conventions in LA and don't really know what I don't know about vector spaces...the book I'm referring to seems to jump straight from the intuition for vector spaces to the solving of problems without teaching the in-betweens. I'm a high school student trying to teach myself LA so I'm quite new to mathematics at the college level. Sorry for the amateurish question.

Answer (score 1):

I think $ex$ is defined by $x^e$

Let us denote by $o$ the zero vector. For each positive number $x$ we get

$$o=x+(-x)=x+x^{-1}=xx^{-1}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

With $$e=3, x=2, y=1 $$

we get  $$ x+y = (xy) =2, e(x+y)=6$$

$$ ex+ey = 6(3) = 18$$
Thus the distributive rule fails.
Also $$x+1 = (1x)=x$$
That is $1$ acts as the $0$ vector.

Comment: why is there the introduction of a comma in the 2nd line? If x=2, won't 2 + 1 = 3 which is not equal to 1 x 2 =2?